# 3 draggable objects with different widths and heights. Align them all horizontally and vertically on the page after buttons click

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-ui, html5-canvas

What i want that are:

1. Create three draggable objects with different widths and heights.
2. Create one-button which aligns them all horizontally and another that aligns them vertically on the page.

Few things i want to share.. Well i have googled similar to this task for few hours. So far i got something like which for only one, one & only single object drag n drop. I don't find anything for multiple objects. I tried to complete this taks on those existing demos. But couldn't not successful.
Can anyone help me? Please. One more thing, it will be better if the solution is provided on jsFiddle or codePen instead of here's code snippet.
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/zVZFq`
```

Please have a look. Although it will not solve your task completely (the way you described) but partially (1st list point) solves. Hopefully, it will push you to complete the task.

**Updated:**
[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rashedrahat/h63ugn1m/60/) i have done the task for you. Hope this will satisfy your task completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Welcome. My pleasure.

Comment: Added new extra the solution related your task. Check please.